# Swift iOS 13 push notifications device token convert in javascript/php/typescript

Tags: javascript, php, ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have a Swift application with push notifications. Whenever the device registered a device token to receive push notifications I got a normal string like: `QY1WcHzcxSbAYPJa0OrTQwFhYZ3ilRUQ0HmKgUlP4IBsLQAJazZnZ4XuGrNO2l4S`. However, with iOS 13 a new device token is received in the format: `{ length = 32, bytes = 0xd3d997af 967d1f43 b405374a 13394d2f ... 28f10282 14af515f }`.

I use the following code to convert the new device token:

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

This gives me back a string with 64 characters.

The original application is not build in swift. How can I make an implementation in javascript/php/typescript where I receive a string like: `{ length = 32, bytes = 0xd3d997af 967d1f43 b405374a 13394d2f ... 28f10282 14af515f }` and convert it to: `QY1WcHzcxSbAYPJa0OrTQwFhYZ3ilRUQ0HmKgUlP4IBsLQAJazZnZ4XuGrNO2l4S`

Comment: What do you mean by "get this to work". How is getting back a string with 64 characters different from your expected behaviour?

Comment: @usernumber It is working in Swift, but the original application is not a Swift application. That's why I ask for a implementation in javascript/php/typescript

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 5.0** you need to use below code.

```
    class func string(fromDeviceToken deviceToken: Data?) -> String? {
    let length = deviceToken?.count ?? 0
    if length == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    let buffer = UInt8(deviceToken?.bytes ?? 0)
    var hexString = String(repeating: "\0", count: length * 2)
    for i in 0..<length {
        hexString += String(format: "%02x", buffer[i])
    }
    return hexString
}
```

And if you are using **Objective-C** then You need to use below code:

```
    + (NSString *)stringFromDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSUInteger length = deviceToken.length;
    if (length == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    const unsigned char *buffer = deviceToken.bytes;
    NSMutableString *hexString  = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:(length * 2)];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        [hexString appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
    }
    return [hexString copy];
}
```

You can check this out [Apple Push Notification Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117545)

Comment: I need an implementation in javascript/php/typescript not swift/obj-c

Comment: @Dicoyo may be this link can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757330/how-to-grab-device-token-from-xcode-to-javascript-in-phonegap-ios